# Duplicates with condition (SQL)

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to get the number of duplicates for `article_id` for each `merchant_id`, **where the `zip_code` is identical.** Please see example below:

**Table**

```
merchant_id     article_id   zip_code 
1               4555         1000
1               4555         1003
1               4555         1000
1               3029         1000
2               7539         1005
2               7539         1005
2               7539         1002
2               1232         1006
3               5555         1000
3               5555         1001
3               5555         1001
3               5555         1001
```

**Output Table**

```
merchant_id     count_duplicate   zip_code
1                2                1000
2                2                1005
3                3                1001
```

This is the query that I am currently using but I am struggling to include the zip_code condition:

```
SELECT merchant_id
       ,duplicate_count
FROM main_table mt 
JOIN(select article_id, count(*) AS duplicate_count
     from main_table
     group by article_id
     having count(article_id) =1) mt_1
ON mt.article_id ON mt_1.article_id = mt.article_id
```

Comment: Are those the results that you want?  I am unclear on what you mean by your criteria.  What does "identical" mean?

Comment: Yes, I would like to count the number of duplicates for product_id where the zip code is identical

Comment: I have updated my output table to make it more clear

Comment: Identical to what?  How is the zip code column calculated?  How do you get "3"?

Comment: The zip_code represents where the product_id is located for each merchant_id. So for each merchant_id I would like to return the number of duplicate product_ids if also the corresponding zip_code is also a duplicate for that given product_id

Answer (score 0):

This seems to return what you want.  I'm not sure why `article_id` is not included in the result set:

```
select merchant_id, zip_code, count(*)
from main_table
group by merchant_id, article_id, zip_code
having count(*) > 1
```